# Add column in Excel based on the value of other columns

Tags: excel

I am pretty new to using Excel and am unaware of its features.

I have data in an excel sheet having 4 columns (customer_id, customer_name, amount_debit, amount_debit).

```
customer_id customer_name   amount_credit   amount_debit    prev_bal    curr_bal
1053        Bhavya Gupta        1000            0             1000        2000
1053        Bhavya Gupta        800             0             200         1000
298          prerna             0               100            0          -100
1053        Bhavya Gupta        200             0              0           200
```

I need to add 2 new columns (which are prev_bal and curr_bal) to the Excel sheet.

The prev_bal and curr_bal should be calculated uniquely for each customer based on its customer id. Is there any way that I can achieve this using script or excel features.

Comment: *The prev_bal and curr_bal should be calculated uniquely* How? I mean, How would be the manual calculation you need to know? this is important to get the best approach

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns by uniquely I mean that for customer_id 1053, I need to get prev_bal and curr_bal values (for each row), and these values should not be related to when calculating for customer id 298. Actually, this is transaction data, so I need to fetch the prev balance and curr balance at each transaction of each customer.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns could you please suggest the best approach by which I can get my desired results ?

Comment: I undertstand that but in Excel you need to know how you would manually do it before choosing a formula, Pivot Table solution, UDF or whatever. So, as example. in your input for customer 1053 you got prev_bal 1000, 200 and 0 ¿How do you calculate that? Same for curr-bal (2000, 1000, 200) How? Without that information, this is a shot in the dark. It looks like a SUMIFS formula would be helpful but not sure without knwing how to calculate

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns initially starting from the bottom row, prev_bal and curr_bal is 0, next if amount is debited, then the curr_bal = curr_bal - amount_debit (if amount_credit in that particular row then curr_bal = cur_bal + amount_credit). And the prev_bal of suppose row 2, would be equal to curr_bal of row 1 (wrt to the customer id)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns considering customer id 1053 (beginning from last row)

**1.** `amount_debit` = 0, `amount_credit` = 200, so `curr_bal` = 0+200=200 , `prev_bal`=0

**2.**  `amount_debit` = 0, `amount_credit` = 800, so `curr_bal` = 200+800=1000 , `prev_bal`=200

**3.**  `amount_debit` = 0, `amount_credit` = 1000, so `curr_bal` = 1000+1000=2000 , `prev_bal`=100

Comment: transaction_id should be in an ascending order from the newest to oldest.

Comment: @Ahmed yes, it is in ascending order. But how can I add the prev_bal and curr_bal according to my requirement ?

Comment: add new column for transaction_id and use the following formula for prev_bal =SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,B2,A:A,">"&A2)-SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,B2,A:A,">"&A2) and =F2+D2-E2 for curr_bal. transaction_id is A, customer_id is B and so on.

Comment: the idea is to find the (sum of all credit - the some of all debit) for all transactions prior to the current one, for a specific customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be using dynamic references to ranges. It's kind of complex but at least it get the output you've posted:

[image]

Formula in column E2 is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F3:$F$6;MATCH(A2;A3:$A$6;0));0)
```

Formula in column F2 is:

```
=SUMIF(A2:$A$5;A2;C2:$C$5)-SUMIF(A2:$A$5;A2;D2:$D$5)
```

Drag both of them to bottom

Please, note my argument separator in functions is the semicolon, depending on your regional settings it might be a comma.

Anyways, I've uploaded the workbook to Gdrive so you can download and check the formulas and test it properly:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rkr6EUHfR7QksDShMlkS97nZBD7e73OV/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true